# d3 dynamically updating nodes based on user selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to enable a user to click nodes in a force layout and reduce the data set to just those nodes and their associated links.

I've gotten as far as this; http://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/4gemo0xe/1/

The section starting at 179;

```
d3.select("#filterResults")
    .on("click", function() {

        //feed the indexes of the selected nodes into array
        var nodeArray = []
        d3.selectAll("circle[fill=\"Red\"]")
            .each(function(d, i) {
                    nodeArray.push(d3.select(this).attr("node-index"))              
            })

        //step2: loop through nodes array and return only those nodes that share
        //index with nodeArray into newNodes
        var newNodes = []
        nodes.forEach(function(nde, idx, list) {
            nodeArray.forEach(function(nde2, idx2, list2) {
                if (idx == nde2) {
                     newNodes.push(nde)   
                }
            })
        })

        //step3: loop through links array and return only those links that
        //have source or target as index of nodes in nodeArray
        var newLinks = []
        links.forEach(function(link, lidx, llist) {
            nodeArray.forEach(function(nde, idx, list) {
                if (link.source == nde || link.target == nde) {
                        newLinks.push(link)
                }
            })
        })
        alert(newLinks.length)

    })
```

is where I'm stuck, specifically step 3. I can't seem to get at the links from within the onclick function, the alert returns zero where it should return however many links are associated with the selected nodes.

Ultimately I want to identify nodes and links associated with the selected and then update the data set to reflect this new data set, if that's even possible! Only one way to find out..

Answer (score 0):

Once force is started, source and target values got replaced with corresponding node objects. So instead of comparing link sources with node index, compare it with the node.

```
if (link.source == nodes[nde] || link.target == nodes[nde]) {
    newLinks.push(link)
}
```

**Or**

```
if (link.source.index == nde || link.target.index ==nde) {
    newLinks.push(link)
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gemo0xe/3/)

> Note: the values of the source and target attributes may be initially
>   specified as indexes into the nodes array; these will be replaced by
>   references after the call to start.

This is the sample structure of a node.

```
{
    fixed: 0,
    index: 12,
    label: "I am an information label",
    px: 287.64956227452404,
    py: 83.71383910494417,
    weight: 7,
    x: 287.7214898272057,
    y: 83.59069881862021
}
```

`d3.select(".node").data()` will return you the data associated with that node, where `node` is the class name.

You can refer more about d3 force layout from [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout).

Comment: "corresponding node objects"? Is there some way I can look at those objects and see what they're made up of? And how is it that force has literally replaced my starting arrays with these node objects? What if I want to get at the array data for another purpose?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle and answer. hope it helps.

Comment: If I loop through the links array and return link.source and use that piece of code directly after declaring var links = graph.links, then I get numeric values as a response. If I use the exact same loop after declaring var force, I get an array of objects returned. Can you explain what's going on there? How can it mess around with the fundamental data set? Sorry to ask so many questions I'm just trying to get my head round what force is actually doing...

Comment: Its okay. Read the second and third paragraph from force.start section [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#start). The doc explains how node and link arrays are changed after force is applied.

Comment: So baffled. So I've declared my nodes and links. I've then initiated the force using these nodes and links. Post initiation I can't reference either nodes and links via the usual methods as demonstrated in my last point - looping through links to get at the source property (the index reference to the node) now not possible with link.source and must now be link.source.index (the links aren't numbers any more - they're actually the node objects?). However if you look at http://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/p98sxoad/1/, I CAN get at the original nodes array when returning the incident node selection?

Comment: Actually that example disproves my point as I renamed the raw data to nodeData and linkData and I'm not referencing those in the loop in question. So what am I comparing there? nodes[link.source] = (as an example) nodes[0] = an object? and node is an object. So comparing them is somehow comparing the two objects against each other? Is that even possible?

Comment: Yeah possible. Here node and link source/target object will be exactly same. If you wanna compare using it's index , use `link.source.index==nde || link.target.index==nde`

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong with my logic here? http://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/yqx8ubct/. Clicking the links doesn't highlight the associated nodes. If I click the nodes, then the objects stored in each node's linkedNodes and incidentLinkSelection are highlighted via node.linkedNodes.style(). Surely, when you click a link, link.source and link.target are the node objects so I should be able to apply style in the same way? Yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Use this code `var srcNode = d3.selectAll(".node")
            .filter(function(d){ return this.__data__==link.source });        
srcNode.style("fill","red");` . You should apply the style to element. You were trying add style to the object.

Comment: Did you see the updated version where I used var connectedNodes? Surely that's referencing the objects stored in nodes? Filtering those and applying styles directly?

Comment: Also isn't there some way to get at the element which the user clicked on? So if I wanted to highlight a path, isn't there some way to locate the element that the user clicked and style that with d3?

Comment: To get the current path use `d3.select(this).style("stroke","red");`

Comment: Ok thank you for your help Gilsha - with any luck one day I'll be the one answering others questions (give it say 15 years at this rate!)

Comment: Oh one final thing although, tracking back to the original point of the thread - what would the process be for taking my selected elements and reducing the data set to just those elements? My thinking is to loop through the nodes and links that are highlighted red, store these in a data set and then somehow drop the other nodes and links from the dataset using exit() and remove()? Not massively clear on how to use those.

Comment: Refere [here](https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36) Best wishes :)

Comment: I read that a couple of days ago - I can follow it but it's not clear what's going on imo :) thanks anyway